# How can I follow relations in ElementCriteriaModels from plugin code?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, relations

In Twig code you can use `craft->entries->relatedTo` to do all sorts of neat things.

From plugin code I am not sure how this works?

```
$c = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$c->section = 'concepts';
$c->relatedTo(array('targetElement'=>$e, 'field'=>'entry'));
$concepts = $c->find();
```

This doesn't throw an error - but it doesn't work either.

How can I use the criteria model to retrieve entries that have some relationship?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close! Try this:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'concepts';
$criteria->limit   = null;
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => $e,
    'field'         => $field
);
$elements = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```

Keep in mind, in this instance, $field is the field object which can be retrieved with something like the following:

```
$singleFieldModel = craft()->fields->getFieldById($singleField);
```

See the documentation (https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/FieldsService) for other ways to get a field object.

Comment: Thanks! Even more valuable than the correction solution was the link to https://craftcms.com/classreference! No more grep'ing the source code!

Comment: Totally. P&T released that a few weeks ago and it's been pretty invaluable.

Comment: Don't know if this has changed since you posted it, but now it seems `field` should get the field handle, and not the field object.