# Direct relation between templates and PHP

Tags: templating, controller

Is there a direct relation between code in templates and PHP code inside a controller for example?
I need to translate

```
{% set relatedProducts = craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo({
                   targetElement: testVariant,
                   field: "productVariants.productSizes"
}) %}
```

into a controller and im not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question has been asked before [How can I follow relations in ElementCriteriaModels from plugin code](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/how-can-i-follow-relations-in-elementcriteriamodels-from-plugin-code). You would want something like this:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'products';
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => $e,
    'field'         => $field
);
$elements = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```

Where `$e` is testVariant, and `$field` is `productVariants.productSizes`, which can be retrieved using `craft()->elements->getElementById(id)` and `craft()->fields->getFieldById(id)` or `getFieldByHandle(handle)` respectively.

To create a controller see the [documentation on Controllers](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers).